# 'Main' object has no attribute 'TabWidget' between parent Ui class "Ui_MainWindow" and child class "Ui_dialog_List"

Tags: python, class, user-interface, attributes, parent

According to the code below, when I try to take the MainTabIndex value from the addLineDialoge function, which is part of the parent Main () class, and try to use it in the child Dialoge_list class, an 'AttributeError:' Main 'object has no attribute' MainTabIndex 'error occurs.
Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Parent class:

```
class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Main, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.addLineButt.clicked.connect(self.addLineDialoge)

def addLineDialoge(self):
    self.**MainTabIndex** = self.MainTab.currentIndex()
    self.**ListTabIndex** = self.ListTab.currentIndex()
    print(self.ListTabIndex)
    addList = Dialoge_list()
    addWaste = Dialoge_Waste()
    if self.MainTab.currentIndex() == 0:
        addList.exec()
    elif self.MainTab.currentIndex() == 1:
        addWaste.exec()
```

Child class:

```
class Dialoge_list(QDialog, Ui_dialog_List):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialoge_list, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.addItemButt.clicked.connect(self.addListToBase)

    def addListToBase(self):
        numCell = self.numLine.text()
        thikCell = self.thikLine.text()
        matCell = self.matLine.text()
        sizeCell = self.sizeLine.text()
        quantityCell = self.quantityLine.text()
        dateinCell = self.dateinLine.text()
        applyCell = self.applyLine.text()
        noticeCell = self.noticeLine.text()
        list_tab = [(numCell,
                     thikCell,
                     matCell,
                     sizeCell,
                     quantityCell,
                     dateinCell,
                     applyCell,
                     noticeCell)]
        if "".__eq__(numCell) and "".__eq__(thikCell) and "".__eq__(matCell) and "".__eq__(
                sizeCell) and "".__eq__(quantityCell) and "".__eq__(dateinCell) and "".__eq__(
            applyCell) and "".__eq__(noticeCell):
            emptyError = EmptyErrorDialoge()
            emptyError.exec()

        elif Main().**MainTabIndex** == 0  and Main().**ListTabIndex** == 0:
             . . . .
```

Comment: the required functions are marked with ** ... **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
It was necessary to make the following changes in the super method of the "Dialoge_list" classWas:

```
class Dialoge_list(QDialog, Ui_dialog_List):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialoge_list, self).__init__()
```

Became:

```
class Dialoge_list(QDialog, Ui_dialog_List):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Dialoge_list, self).__init__(parent)
```

Also made changes to the addListToBase function.Was:

```
def addLineDialoge(self):
    self.MainTabIndex = self.MainTab.currentIndex()
    self.ListTabIndex = self.ListTab.currentIndex()
    print(self.ListTabIndex)
    addList = Dialoge_list()
. . .
```

Became

```
def addLineDialoge(self):
    self.MainTabIndex = self.MainTab.currentIndex()
    self.ListTabIndex = self.ListTab.currentIndex()
    print(self.ListTabIndex)
    addList = Dialoge_list(self)
. . .
```

After that, in the child class, you can call the MainTabIndex and ListTabIndex functions, waiting for this you just need to add the method parent(). Was:

```
class Dialoge_list(QDialog, Ui_dialog_List):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialoge_list, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.addItemButt.clicked.connect(self.addListToBase)
```

Became:

```
class Dialoge_list(QDialog, Ui_dialog_List):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialoge_list, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.addItemButt.clicked.connect(self.addListToBase)
        self.MainTabIndex = str(self.parent().MainTab.currentIndex())
        self.ListTabIndex = str(self.parent().ListTab.currentIndex())
```

And only after that, the values of these functions can be used anywhere in the child class.